# struct mystruct a = b; Is this valid? Direct assignment of structure variables, is it valid in C?

Tags: c, coding-style

I have the following code.

```
struct rectangle {
int length;
int breadth;
};

int main (void) 
{
    struct rectangle a,b;
    a.length = 10;
    a.breadth = 5;

    b=a;  
    printf("\nValues of b.length = %d, b.breadth=%d\n",b.length,b.breadth);
    return 0;
}
```

**Is the above assignment a valid statement?(b=a)** I did it this way inside my project. I got a **review comment** stating, **this type of assignment is wrong and i should have done used memcpy**. I printed the values of b and checked. The values are correct. I was wondering why the above assignment is wrong? **If it is wrong what happens when you pass a structure variable to a function and catch it in a separate variable?** I hope i am clear on my question. Please get back to me if i am unclear on my question.

Comment: Your code is indeed invalid, but it is due to the `main` signature, not the assignment.

Comment: Can you please tell me whats wrong with the main signature?

Comment: main should return int. (unless: blablabala)

Comment: There is no "unless", it has to return an `int`. There are just two valid `main` signatures: `int main(int, char**)` and `int main()`. In some version of C it is possible to omit the `return 0` (maybe C99?) but that's it.

Comment: There is an unless, intended for "freestanding implementations". And the second signature should be `int main(void)`

Comment: `int main(void)`!!! `int main()`is *not* a signature.

Comment: @tristopia: it is, but it just does not assure proper typechecking. Hardly a problem, since you shoudln't ever call the `main` function by yourself, so it is just a matter of style.

Comment: @wildplasser: you are indeed right (about the freestanding thing).

Comment: Also please answer to my comment posted on Unwinds answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reviewer is, in my opinion, misguided. It's very correct, struct values are just like any other, it's just fine to assign them. And it's way, way, clearer than invoking `memcpy()`, and much (much!) less error-prone.

I always have to stop and think about what to pass as the third argument to `memcpy()` when copying the same type of value, since I find it non-obvious which choice is the clearest. So, that's one less pedagogical problem, and of course it just reads better.

Also, the compiler *might* be smart enough *not* to copy any additional padding and/or alignment bytes that might lurk in there, something `memcpy()` can never do. It's a higher-level construct, and thus "simply better".

Comment: I just checked with the reviewer. He mentioned, the review comment was given because, this process would make it complicated if the structure  has a pointer inside it. How far is this valid? And one more thing which he was pointing out is that, the compilers are optimising the assignment but according to original C stnadards and the compilers that are adhering these standards, this type of assignment is wrong..

Comment: @happy2Help: I think he is a bit confused, since what he said does not make any sense:
A) So he concur that the assignment is valid C, but that it does not work if you want a deep copy. Right, but neither memcpy is sufficient in this case, since the assignment and memcpy are semantically equivalent. And BTW, you want a shallow copy or a deep one? And you have pointers in the first place?
B) You are writing your code against a specific version of the language. Are you writing for C89/C99 or some ancient pre-ANSI C? I think the answer is obvious, so his remark is plainly stupid.

Comment: The pointer argument is plain bogus. It is about semantics. And there *is no* pointer in the OP's example. I agree, there are places where a "deep copy* is needed, but this is not one of them.

Comment: I suggest suggesting your boss about replacing that guy with someone more competent.

Answer (score 4):

It is, and I think always has been, valid code and your review comment is **wrong**.

In my view the review comment is bad because the reviewer is misleading you into bad habits - we use memcpy when we want to copy arbitrary bits of memory - and by definition a struct is well defined and it's cleaner, easier to read, and simply your way is right.

If you pass a struct by value to a function, e.g.

```
struct a some_function(struct a)
{
    a.width = 99;
    return a;
}
```

The value passed in is a copy, and the return value is also a copy, the only danger here is when the struct is big and results in an overhead for each call.

If this didn't work then most of the C world would fall apart...

To take onboard the reviewers comments, in my opinion they are digging themselves deeper into a whole and should just admit being wrong.

There is no difference between the two statements

```
memcpy(&b, &a, sizeof(b));
b = a;
```

If a compiler is optimising then it shouldn't break the original code; otherwise that's a fault in the compiler - it's hokum mentioning the original C standard (i.e. C89) as I doubt very much that the standard permits faulty optimisation.

For interest, rather than proof of anything I just tried this on a pre-ansi compiler (from 1986) in a standard unix environment.

```
/tmp> gcc a.c
a.c:
C-68000U 1.8.0 Copyright (c)1985,1986 Green Hills Software, Inc.
linking a:
/tmp> ./a
10, 5
```

For further interest, maybe only mine! I've built with optimisation and looked at the generated code.

The results show that this ancient, pre standard compiler works as expected. The proof in 68k is below - I've added comments with // to explain  what's happening.

As you can see, the only result of optimising is that the generated code is more efficient both in terms of space and also execution time - not that that matters much unless you're working in an embedded environment

```
    ;       line  #13 memcpy(&b, &a, sizeof(b));
     140     PEA    0x8           // size
     144     PEA    (-8,FP)       // &a
     148     PEA    (-16,FP)      // &b
     152     JSR    memcpy        // call memcpy

    ;       line  #14
     170     LEA    (-8,FP),A1   // &a
     174     LEA    (-16,FP),A0  // &b
     178     MOVE.L (A1)+,(A0)+  // copy first element of struct
     180     MOVE.L (A1)+,(A0)+  // copy second element
```

for a larger struct the code generated for `b=a` is

```
     170     LEA    (-112,FP),A1
     174     LEA    (-224,FP),A0
     178     MOVEQ  #27,D0
     180     MOVE.L (A1)+,(A0)+
     182     DBF    D0,main+60
```

which is exactly the same size as the `memcpy` version - but will execute faster.

So in summary **the original reviewer was wrong and is still wrong and should admit their mistake** - unless they are referring to a specific case that they can prove (which I doubt)

Comment: The fact that it compiles with a 1986 compiler does not mean anything.

Comment: @akappa yeah point taken, it's just that I remember this has always worked even pre-ANSI C89 and wanted to check it.

Comment: @wildplasser void main() being wrong would have been a valid review comment too...

Comment: Struct assignment has always been legal. VLA's will probably be an exception in C99. (just like the struct hack)

Comment: Please find the comment i provided on unwinds solution

Comment: @happy2Help I've answered the reviewers further arguments above.

Answer (score 0):

Your colleague is probably thinking of an array, where the assignment statement is not valid.

Since arrays and structs are both grouped together as *aggregates*, he may have thought the same restriction applies to variables of struct type.

However, please note that this assignment is the same as `memcpy` in C, but not necessarily in C++ (for POD types it is still the same).  That may be sufficient reason for a coding standard to forbid it, in which case you should follow your company's coding standard.